# Boost documents in search results which are matched to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have this relatively complex search query that's already being built and working with perfect sorting.

But I think here searching is slow just because of script so all I want to remove script and write query accordingly.

**current code :-**

```
"sort": [
{
  "_script": {
    "type": "number",
    "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": "double pscore = 0;for(id in params.boost_ids){if(params._source.midoffice_master_id == id){pscore = -999999999;}}return pscore;",
      "params": {
        "boost_ids": [
         3,
         4,
         5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Above code explaination:-

For example, if a match query would give a result like:

```
[{m_id: 1, name: A}, {m_id: 2, name: B}, {m_id: 3, name: C}, {m_id: 4, name: D}, ...]
```

So I want to boost document with m_id array [3, 4, 5] which would then transform the result into:

```
[{m_id: 3, name: C}, {m_id: 4, name: D}, {m_id: 1, name: A}, {m_id: 2, name: B}, ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the below query using [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)(for boosting) and [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) (used to query array of values)

Note that the logic I've mentioned is in the `should` clause of the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}   //just a sample must clause to retrieve all docs
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "function_score": {     <---- Function Score Query
            "query": {
              "terms": {          <---- Terms Query
                "m_id": [
                  3,4,5
                ]
              }
            },
            "boost": 100          <---- Boosting value
          }
        }
      ]
    } 
  }
}
```

So basically, you can remove the sort logic completely and add the above `function query` in your `should` clause, which would give you the results in the order you are looking for.

Note that you'd have to find a way to add the logic correctly in case if you have much complex query, and if you are struggling with anything, do let me know. I'd be happy to help!!

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey @code_aks, was the above solution useful? Let me know if you need any help!!

Comment: I need more help !! above solution is giving only matched data (which is matched with m_id only) which is in should clause, other document are not listed while I just want to boost the record which is matched with m_id and other records can also list but after boosted records. I would like to connect with you on chat so I can describe my overall query. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: hey @code_aks, could we have a session sometime today around 7 PM IST today. I won't be available earlier. Anytime after 7 PM, let me know what time you'd want. Happy to help!!

Comment: hey @kamal sure :). I will be available today at 8 PM IST.

Comment: Cool, I'll be there!!

Comment: Hey @kamal.. are you there??

Comment: I'll be there in 5 mins

Comment: Hey @Opster ES Ninja - Kamal please help me to sort out this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60013921/in-which-order-elasticsearch-filters-applied